# django login showing AnonymousUser after login

Tags: django

```
def loggin(req):
    if req.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    if req.POST:
        username=req.POST['username']
        password=req.POST['password']
        usr = authenticate(req,username=username,password=password)
        if usr is not None:
            login(req,usr)
            return redirect(reverse('home'))
    return render(req,'cart/login.html')
def home(req):
    if req.user.is_authenticated:
        name=req.user
        context = {
                'name':name,
        }
        return render(req,'cart/home.html',context)
```

My settings.py are fine and have no error in code but after successful get logged in redirection to home view shows AnonymousUser.I dont know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Don't you have `Anonimous` hardcoded in ,'anon/home.html' template? The prefix causes some doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is becouse your are sending the user object instead than the name

```
req.user.username
```

Then you have a typo

```
if req.method == 'POST':
```